# How to show quick hint exports interface

Tags: typescript, autocomplete

my code

[image]

types

[image]

I'm trying to see what type I'm exporting, if you hover the mouse, you can't see anything, you need to hold down alt to see the incoming type in the specified interface.
how to cook properly?

example: index.ts

```
import { NEW_TYPE } from './types';

const example = ({ one, two }: NEW_TYPE) => {
    console.log(`[LOG] two`, `<${typeof two}>`, two);
    console.log(`[LOG] one`, `<${typeof one}>`, one);
};
```

example: types.d.ts

```
export interface NEW_TYPE {
   one: number;
   two: string;
 }
```

Comment: That's not your code. That's an unnecessary image. Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your post and formatted for readability. Please read [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), and then come back and [edit] your code to provide the actual code.

Comment: @KenWhite, update